# Automated Webpage Software (Alternative to Selenium) that uses Jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, selenium

I have been building a lot of automated webpage entry programs for a client using Selenium.

These programs will extract data from the clients database, and automatically log into webpages and enter the data. These webpages do not have an API I can connect to, so I must simulate a human.

The problem is that I am finding it much harder to traverse, click, set inputs using the Selenium Web Driver than I would if I just wrote the commands in console with Jquery loaded.

I have tried using the Execute Script command in Selenium, but am unable to jquery commands when the site does not have jquery libraries.

I have looked into PhatomJs, but I require a Head (browser) to debug, i can turn off the head when it goes into production.

I have also looked at CasperJs, but still have an issue that there is no debugging browser that is controlled.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Rephrased the questions as suggested.